# NOT IN usage with GROUP BY and HAVING

Tags: google-bigquery

We are trying to SUM all order revenue, where we didn't registered payment success event. (eg: failed orders) A failed order is either without payment attempt, or a failed payment event.

```
SELECT
o.campaign.id AS campaign_id,
o.campaign.template_id AS campaign_template_id,
o.campaign.lang AS language,
o.campaign.split_idx AS campaign_split_id,
count(distinct o.order_id) AS orders,
SUM(o.total) AS totalrevenue,
SUM(o.shipping_value) AS shipping_value
FROM [wr_live.order] AS o
GROUP BY campaign_id, campaign_template_id, language, campaign_split_id
HAVING
o.order_id NOT IN (
SELECT order_id
FROM [wr_live.order_event] as e
WHERE e.order_id = o.order_id AND e.event = 'payment' and e.status = 1
)
```

.

```
Query Failed
Error: Field 'o.order_id' not found in table 'e'; did you mean 'order_id'?
Job ID: aerobic-forge-504:job_h41lud83lyqiD7p6qldXMl_tx0A
```

As you see we are running a NOT IN clause where we check if there we don't have for that particular order any event with payment, and status =1.

We have Case 05024161 on paid Google enterprise support, but apparently they were not able to help.

Comment: Can you make a public sample dataset available to play with the query?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I already shared the dataset with google support.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Apparently could you investigate why the support was not able to answer this quite rapidly. Also it turns out there is no official BQ support, can you confirm this?

Comment: There is support and they should be covering BigQuery. Please escalate through support if the answer is not satisfactory. Meanwhile I have limited resources to investigate this issue further - I'm traveling with limited connectivity. As you can see this doesn't stop me from looking at StackOverflow once in a while to help wherever I can.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa the answer is satisfactory here on SO, but the support  was not able to help me for 4 days. And that is something I want to understand. Mario tells me he is not part of BQ and he doesn't have the experience, and looks like there is no one from BQ to answer the tickets added to the paid enterprise support.

Comment: :(, let me see what can I do about this

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Now I am told on the case that, `product teams don't interact with customers.` so this is freaking weird. Anyway I got the answers for this one, but there are other cases open. Is there a better way to address this to the BQ team?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Note that the HAVING clause can only refer to fields defined in your SELECT clause (if the field has an alias, you must use it; if it doesn't, use the aggregate field name instead)."

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#having

in your query there is no "Order_Id" in the select clause.
try putting it in a where clause before the group by.

something like:

```
SELECT
o.campaign.id AS campaign_id,
o.campaign.template_id AS campaign_template_id,
o.campaign.lang AS language,
o.campaign.split_idx AS campaign_split_id,
count(distinct o.order_id) AS orders,
SUM(o.total) AS totalrevenue,
SUM(o.shipping_value) AS shipping_value
FROM(
Select * from  [wr_live.order] 
Where order_id NOT IN (
SELECT order_id
FROM [wr_live.order_event] as e
WHERE  e.event = 'payment' and e.status = 1
) 
)AS o
GROUP BY campaign_id, campaign_template_id, language, campaign_split_id
```

In addition BQ does not support sub-query reference to parent query. if you need it, try to replace with Join

Comment: I tried yours and it's the same: `Query Failed
Error: Field 'o.order_id' not found in table 'e'; did you mean 'order_id'?`

Comment: I wrote this blindly, with no real schema to refer to... apparently i missed something. check after my edit.

Comment: I checked after your edit, and still the same error msg `Error: Field 'o.order_id' not found in table 'e'; did you mean 'order_id'?
Job ID: aerobic-forge-504:job_5XQTd_R8BUfAx1MlY80cRpetmyI`

Comment: BQ does not support sub-query reference to parent query. if you need it, try to replace with Join

Comment: It works now, but it takes decent time `62.9s elapsed`.

Answer (score 1):

As a member of the BigQuery team, I was able to run your query and experiment with different approaches.  It seems that it can run with an anti-join (NOT IN) as long as you remove the reference to o.order_id and modify some of the field names.

```
SELECT
  campaign.id AS campaign_id,
  campaign.template_id AS campaign_template_id,
  campaign.lang AS language,
  campaign.split_idx AS campaign_split_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS orders,
  SUM(total) AS totalrevenue,
  SUM(shipping_value) AS shipping_value
FROM
  [wr_live.order]
WHERE
  order_id NOT IN (
  SELECT
    order_id
  FROM
    [wr_live.order_event]
  WHERE
    event = 'payment'
    AND status = 1
    )
GROUP BY
  campaign_id,
  campaign_template_id,
  language,
  campaign_split_id;
```

This query ran a few times in less than 10 seconds.  I can't guarantee that it will always be that fast, but you might want to try it.